# Postgres point type column to Spring Entity data type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry
(
    id          serial not null primary key,
    coordinates point not null

);
```

and I am trying to retrieve a row  as JSON response API from a server which uses Spring, with the class below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "geometry",schema = "public")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=RefIntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Cylinder
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private Point coordinates;

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Point getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to access the end point I get:

```
could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

Comment: can you give github link with reproducer ?

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using hibernate orm you need to tell him that you expect to deserialize an postgis object : org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect